# Parse unpinFromBackground doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I'm currently using Parse to save details about users in an app. When the ViewController is loaded for the first time, the user data is retrieved from the server. When the user leaves the ViewController, I use the code [user pinInBackground] to save user variables to the local datastore. When the ViewController is reloaded later, the user variables are set using the data from the local datastore. This works correctly in my app.

However, when the user leaves to a specific view controller, on returning to the original ViewController, I wish for the app to access the data from the server instead of the local datastore. To do this, I use the code:

```
[user fetchFromLocalDatastoreInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

                [user unpinInBackgroundWithName:@"MAINPIN" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                    [user fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"personalHeaderString is equal to %@", user[pfPersonalHeader]]);
                    }];

                }];
            }];
```

The NSLog shows that the code is definitely run as intended. However, the NSLog also shows that the data is not unpinned, and instead the app continues to use data from the local datastore, rather than fetching the data from the Parse server as fetch is supposed to do. How can I fix this?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you are fetching from the local datastore before you unpin? I'm guessing that when you pin the result initially you give it the name "MAINPIN" so why not use:

> PFObject.unpinInBackgroundWithName:("MAINPIN")

and then run a your "live" query after after this?

More info here:  https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/unpinInBackgroundWithName:

Andrew